# Subreport with JsonDatasource

Tags: json, jasper-reports, ireport

I have this error when I try to use subreport with a JsonDatasource in my iReport 4.5.1 Window:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource
```

I don't understand why...
The subreport expresion is

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource(new java.net.URL($P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.source}).openStream(),"response.tickets")
```

This is the full text Exception [click_here](http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/8790/subreportexception.jpg)

How I can to resolve this Exception?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use iReport 4.5.1 but I managed to solve the same problem on 4.6.0 platform.

iReport do not include all jasperreports libraries by default, I found that it includes only:

- hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar
- jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar
- jasperreports-core-renderer.jar

All you have to do is adding the jasperreports json library into the classpath by clicking the menu tools/options, then in the ireport section clicking on the classpath tabber.

Then click "Add Jar" button and browse to add the missing jar from \iReport-4.6.0\ireport\modules\ext\jasperreports-json.jar

I hope it's not too late...

Comment: Your solution solves the problem in iReport, but when I execute the report and subreport in code through web app, only shows the header data and the detail data shows nothing (in subreport). Apparently subdatasource interpretation of expression is not correct, but if successful iReport. Any idea for this problem?